# How to get query result using recursive function?

Tags: php, recursion

I have a phonecode 1234 and i am checking this phonecode in my db to get its respective's country's name if matched i am returning country's name  anf if not matched i am removing the last digit from phone code example 123 and checking again if matched i am returning the country name otherwise removing the last digit again example 12 until i reach 1.

```php
function rFunc($val)
{
    if (strlen($val) != 0) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name from country Where phonecode='$val'LIMIT 1");
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            $res  = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
            $name = $res['name'];
            return $name;
        } else {
            rFunc(substr($val, 0, -1));
        }
    } else {
        return "N/A";
    }
}
$value = "1234";
$na    = rFunc($value);
```

Comment: You need to put a `return` in front of your recursing `rFunc()` call, otherwise its return value will get lost.

Comment: @Qirel Wow, that looks so much better!

Comment: Could you not simply use a `regexp` operator within the sql - like `select name from country where phonecode regexp 1234`??

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Unformatted code is so much harder to read... Unreadable code is harder to troubleshoot... ;-)

Comment: Thankx @KIKOSoftware

Comment: @RamRaider: Isn't `phonecode regexp 1234` equivalent to `phonecode LIKE '%1234%'`? That's not what is wanted here. I'm not that good with regular expressions.

Comment: it is similar yes - just thought it might be a quicker approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add return in your recursive function.

```
return rFunc(substr($val,0,-1));
```